# Why can't case_when return different-length vectors?

Tags: r, dplyr

This fails:

```
library(tidyverse)
myFn <- function(nmbr){
  case_when(
    nmbr > 3 ~ letters[1:3],
    TRUE ~ letters[1:2]
  )
}

myFn(4)
# Error: `TRUE ~ letters[1:2]` must be length 3 or one, not 2
# Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

*Why* does it fail? Why is `case_when` built in such a way that its branches can't return different-length vectors?  I'd like `myFn` to work so that I can do things like:

```
tibble(fruit = c("apple", "grape"),
       count = 3:4) %>% 
  mutate(bowl = myFn(count)) %>% 
  unnest(col = "bowl")
```

and get

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
fruit count  bowl
<chr> <int> <int>
1 apple     3     a
2 apple     3     b
3 grape     4     a
4 grape     4     b
5 grape     4     c
```

I can get it to work - by writing a non-vectorized `myFn` using `if/else`, then wrapping it in `map`, but why should I have to?

Comment: Because one underlying tenet of `data.frame`s (and therefore tibbles) is that each column be exactly the same length.

Comment: Right.  But in my example, `fruit` and `count` are both length 2, and `bowl` would be a list of 2 vectors.

Comment: Yes, and calls within `mutate` must always return the same length as the number of rows going in (or 1), and `summarise` must always return length 1.

Comment: Man, I'm having a hard time writing vectorized functions; things that look to me like they *ought to* work keep biting me.  Is there a good Vignette, book chapter, article or SO thread that's sort of a tutorial?  Tips, tricks and pitfalls?

Comment: @henrik - I like it already.  Nice that a book about the R Inferno is written by a guy named _Burns_.    I'd buy a copy, but used copies are $102 on Amazon.  Nice of him to put the pdf online.

Comment: @henrik - OTOH, it was written long before `dplyr` came along, so it couldn't discuss `case_when` or `recode`, etc.

Comment: Yeah, I've got  *Advanced R* hardcopy open on my desk.  But in *17.6 Vectorize* he lays out *why* I should vectorize, but doesn't say *how to* write vectorized functions.  I'm still looking for vectorization tutorial, covering fairly complex examples.  *Vectorization for Dummies*

Comment: @henrik E.g. using `str_split` and `str_match`, I end up with a lot of character matrices.  I recombine them in complex ways, depending on conditions like punctuation.  (E.g., transforming `"BOLT, LAG"` to `c("BOLT", ",","LAG")` to `LAG BOLT`.) I've been slicing them up by rows and operating serially on the vectors.  I'd like to use vectorized functions from `tidyverse` and operate on whole matrix.  I've been making some progress through a lot of trial-and-error.

Comment: Maybe in another 3 months I'll be ready to post a * Vectorization for Dummies* guide myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per my comments, your function needs to return one element for each row of input. However, each of those elements can be a `list` of length 0 or more (and arbitrary complexity). Try this:

```r
myFn <- function(nmbr){
  case_when(
    nmbr > 3 ~ list(letters[1:3]),
    TRUE ~ list(letters[1:2])
  )
}
tibble(fruit = c("apple", "grape"),
       count = 3:4) %>%
  mutate(bowl = myFn(count))
# # A tibble: 2 x 3
#   fruit count bowl     
#   <chr> <int> <list>   
# 1 apple     3 <chr [2]>
# 2 grape     4 <chr [3]>
tibble(fruit = c("apple", "grape"),
       count = 3:4) %>%
  mutate(bowl = myFn(count)) %>%
  unnest(col = "bowl")
# # A tibble: 5 x 3
#   fruit count bowl 
#   <chr> <int> <chr>
# 1 apple     3 a    
# 2 apple     3 b    
# 3 grape     4 a    
# 4 grape     4 b    
# 5 grape     4 c
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending r2Evans answer, you can unlist prior to returning. Here is my code that I am using as part of my nesting algorithm.

```
test_fn <- function(StockCode) {
  L <- dplyr::case_when(stringr::str_starts(StockCode, "A") ~ list(7500),
                        stringr::str_starts(StockCode, "FL") ~ list(6000),
                        stringr::str_starts(StockCode, "PIPE") ~ list(6500),
                        stringr::str_starts(StockCode, "RHS") ~ 
                          list(c(8000, 12000)),
                        stringr::str_starts(StockCode, "RND") ~ list(6000),
                        stringr::str_starts(StockCode, "SQ") ~ list(6000),
                        TRUE ~
                          list(c(9000, 10500, 12000, 13500, 15000, 16500, 18000))) %>%
    unlist()
  return(L)
}

test_fn("RHS")
test_fn("CH")
```

The output will be the vector assigned to the list.